# Debugging Python in TextWrangler shows Terminal not Debugger

Tags: python, textwrangler

When I am debugging python code in TextWrangler using the #! | Run in Debugger option the code is run in a terminal not in the python debugger. How do I configure TextWrangler to use the python debugger?

BTW - Using TextWrangler v3.5 (2880) running on a Mac, python file has .py extension and is seen by TextWrangler as a python file; syntax highlighting is correct.

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal that TextWranger opens up when you click on #! | Run in Debugger is the debug environment provided by TextWrangler. It's a command-line utility similar to gdb (from the GNU toolchain) if you've ever used that before. When the terminal opens, if you see this prompt: **(pdb)** then that means you're in the debugger. Typing help at the prompt will get you the available list of commands.